# Setting main font using Lualatex does not have any effect

Tags: fonts, luatex, fontspec

the problem i am facing is the following.
For a thesis i need to set the font type a specific one, so i decided to use Lualatex for that.
Used a given template which i modified.
It does not throw any errors and compiles fine, but the change in the /setmainfont does not have any effect at all.
Thought something might be overwriting it so positioned the setter at the end of the declarations but that did not help either.

for the example, to easily determine if it has an effect, tried to set it to Comic Sans MS

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
% !TeX TXS-program:bibliography = txs:///biber
%!TeX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass[%
draft=false,%
paper=a4,% 
fontsize=12pt,%
pagesize=auto,%pdftex,%
twoside=false,%
headings=small,openany,% 
chapterprefix=false,% 
version=last,%
titlepage=true,%
parskip=half+,%
mpinclude=false,%
headsepline=true,%
toc=bibliography,%
toc=index,%
numbers=noendperiod%
]{scrbook}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage} 
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\ohead[]{\pagemark}
\chead{}
\ihead{\headmark}
\ofoot[]{}
\cfoot[]{}
\automark[chapter]{chapter}
\automark*[section]{}
\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{scrheadings}

\usepackage[left=3.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,includeheadfoot]{geometry}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[full]{textcomp}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath,newtxtt}

\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage[babel]{microtype}
\usepackage{ellipsis}

\clubpenalty = 10000
\widowpenalty = 10000
\displaywidowpenalty = 10000

\usepackage[autostyle,babel,german=guillemets,style=german]{csquotes}
\usepackage[USenglish,ngerman]{babel} 
\selectlanguage{ngerman}

\setkomafont{sectioning}{\rmfamily\bfseries}
\setkomafont{title}{\normalfont\rmfamily}
\setkomafont{descriptionlabel}{\rmfamily}
\setkomafont{caption}{\small\itshape} 
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\normalfont\normalcolor\footnotesize}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}

\setcaptionalignment{c}
\setcapindent{0pt}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{german}

\usepackage[%
 backend=biber,%
 style=apa7,% 
 bibstyle=authoryear,%
 citestyle=authoryear,%
 natbib=false,%
 sorting=anyt,%
 sortcites=true,%
 hyperref=auto,%
 maxnames=3,%
 isbn=false,%
 url=false,%
 maxbibnames=99,%
 minnames=1,%
 dashed=false%
]{biblatex}

\bibliography{bib}

\setlength{\bibitemsep}{1em}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\urlstyle{rm}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0,0,.5}
\hypersetup{%
   pdfauthor={Author},%
   pdfstartview=FitH,%
   pdfpagelayout=OneColumn,%
   naturalnames=true,%
   colorlinks=true,%
   breaklinks=true,%
   linkcolor=blue,%
   citecolor=black,%
   filecolor=black,%
   urlcolor=black}
   
\newcommand{\meta}[1]{\texttt{#1}}
\newcommand{\fat}[1]{\textbf{#1}} 
\newcommand{\product}[1]{\textsc{#1}} 

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{/img}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{varioref}

\newcommand{\verylongpage}{\enlargethispage{2\baselineskip}}

\usepackage[ngerman=ngerman-x-latest]{hyphsubst}
\hyphenation{}

\usepackage{xspace} 

\newenvironment{myquote}{\begin{quote} \small}{\end{quote}}

\renewcommand\uppertitleback[1]{\thispagestyle{empty}#1\vfill}
\renewcommand\lowertitleback[1]{#1}

\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{gray}{.70}

\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.85}

\newmdenv[%
backgroundcolor=light-gray,
linecolor=light-gray,
skipabove=1\baselineskip,
skipbelow=1\baselineskip,
]{shaded}

\newmdenv[%
linecolor=black,
outerlinewidth=1pt,
skipabove=1\baselineskip,
skipbelow=1\baselineskip,
]{syntax}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{andothers={et\addabbrvspace al\adddot}}

\usepackage{fontspec}
% \setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setmainfont{Comic Sans MS}
\setsansfont{Arial}
\setmonofont{Courier New}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
```

Would be so glad if anyone knows why it has no effect and how to fix that problem :)

Comment: Welcome to TeX StackExchange! If you delete the line where you load `newtxtext,newtxmath,newtxtt`, this should solve your issue. These three packages set the document font, so they conflict with your use of Comic Sans in `fontspec`. Just a tip for your future journeys through LaTeX—it's best to delete packages where you don't know their purpose. This helps you to avoid any unknown and unwanted behavior :)

Comment: Also, when using LuaLaTeX to compile a document, don't load the `inputenc`,  `fontenc`, and `textcomp` packages.

Comment: Thanks so much, it did work; did not comment the old stuff which was given in our template out because i thought if it is not used, will probably not matter. Seems this all got loaded up anyways, seems i need to read into how all this comments work and what is commonly used more if i find the time :)

Answer (score 2):

To summarize the earlier comments: You must get rid of -- or comment out -- the following code chunk:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[full]{textcomp}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath,newtxtt}
```

The `inputenc`, `fontenc`, and `textcomp` packages should not be loaded when compiling a document with LuaLaTeX or, for that matter, XeLaTeX. And, by loading the `newtxtext`, `newtxmath`, and `newtxtt` -- which don't seem to be needed anyway -- *before* loading the all-important `fontspec` package, you inhibit the proper operation of the later `\set[main/sans/mono/]font` directives.

Incidentally, is there no math material in your document? If there is, you may want to (a) load the `unicode-math` package instead of the `fontspec` package and (b) issue a suitable `\setmathfont` directive. That said, I cannot think of a decent math font that mixes and matches well with `Comic Sans`. :-)

Some additional comments, in no particular order: It's not a good idea to load both `babel` and `polyglossia`. Don't load packages more than once (cf 'color' and 'xcolor'). `\bibliography{bib}` is deprecated; do write `\addbibresource{bib.bib}`; the filename extension is mandatory. Be sure to load the `xurl` package to allow line breaks at arbitrary positions in URL strings. I'd use the `enumitem` package, not the `enumerate` package, to customize the properties of list-like environments.

Comment: Thanks , it did work, and i changed the commands you recommended as well. Not sure if math formulas are needed since it is about a review, will look into this further if i find the time. Seems one really has to know some tweaks using Latex. Somehow i think the unmodified version of the template had (almost?) the same prospects as now using it with the lualatex and Times New Roman... But i wanted be sure it is exactly this font since it was listed as requirement ;) And seems it is a newer engine anyway, making some settings from before deprecated which i dont understand all functionality yet